# binary quadratic mixed integer nonlinear programming to inequalities

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I have this unconstrained z=x.y where x,y are 0-1 integers. How to reformulate that into set of mixed integer linear inequalities with exactly the same feasible region?

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ and $y$ are $1$, then $z$ has to be 1, $z \geq x+ y-1$

If $x$ and/or $y$ is $0$, then $z$ has to be 0, $z \leq x$, $z \leq y$

Comment: You will also have to add the constraint $0\leq z \le1$. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: or typically you would define z as binary